# EventInfo.AddEventHandler for EventHandler with unknown type parameter

Tags: c#

I'd like to be able to add a generic event handler for a given `EventInfo`. Is it possible at all?

Use case is as following: I have an object. For each event of this object i'd like to add a handler which does something. Object events are gathered via reflection. Code like this i'm using to add handlers:

```
var evt = obj.GetType().GetEvent("OnAdd");
var publisher = new EventPublisher();
EventHandler<object> h = publisher.Publish;
evt.AddEventHandler(obj, h);

// later 
public class EventPublisher
{
    public void Publish(object sender, object payload)
    {
    }
}

// somewhere in obj
public event EventHandler<int> OnAdd;
```

However it works only for `EventHanlder<object>`. E.g. `EventHandler<int>` can't be converted to `EventHandler<object>`.

Is there anyway i can cast any `EventHandler` to `EventHandler<object>` or add event handler some other way?

Comment: You cannot simply cast one type to another. You have to create a whole new delegate instance that refers to a method that will invoke the method in question. For example, in the code you show above, `EventHandler<int> h = (s, e) => Publish(s, e);` See marked duplicate for additional info. Note that what's really preventing you from just assigning the method directly is that the target handler type involves a value type; delegate method group variance would allow use of your `Publish()` method with any other reference type as the `EventHandler<T>`'s `T` type.

Comment: @PeterDuniho but i need to support not only `<int>` type but whatever type the event is. Btw it doesn't work for custom objects as well. Not only for primitive types

Comment: _"it doesn't work for custom objects as well"_ -- not true. As I said, it is strictly a value type vs. reference type issue. If your "custom object" is a value type, then yes...you can't use the method directly. But any custom reference type will work. For value types, you need to wrap your method in one that matches the event, like I said.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks a lot! Question you mentioned helped! I started to write code with `int` example and came to overall incorrect code, which didn't work for non primitives too. It turns out the issue really was with because of primitive type.